# Android - App not showing in Market for some devices

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

we already searched **a lot** of similar topics on StackOverflow and in other forums but haven't managed to solve this issue so far.

We developed an Android application that is **missing from the market** for some devices. It uses geo-data and the camera extensively. **The "Copy Protection" is already off**, and we can't figure why it isn't showing on some devices that appear to be completely compatible.

*The manifesto is as follows:*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.syncmobile.riogastronomia"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.2.1" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION" />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />



     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" /> 

    <supports-screens
        android:xlargeScreens="false"
    />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  >

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</manifest>
```

#### Devices that we're having problem with so far:

> **Model:** *Xperia x10*  |  **Model Number:** *X10i*  |  **Android Version:** *2.3.3*

If you would like to see if it shows up in your device the app name is: "***Rio Gastronomia***"

Thank you all beforehand for your precious time. =D

### Update:

I opened the app direct URL in the browser and I got this message from the market:

> Your content filtering level doesn't allow you to download this item.

The app maturity level is set to **low**.

So... after getting this error from the market I tried switching my filtering configuration. It was set to *"Everyone"*, when I set it to *"All Apps"* I could finally see the app in the market. But I can't change the settings in my users devices, so what should I do to get people that have *"Everyone"* set to see our app?

(The app is set to *"Low Maturity"* cause the option *"Everyone"* was disabled by Google Play)

Comment: First result in search for me (Atrix/Android2.3/USA/AT&T).

Comment: did you check if that phone has all the `uses-features` in your manifest?

Comment: How about the glEsVersion setting? That might prevent a phone from seeing the app if it's graphics package was out of date.

Comment: Thanks guys, we already tested the same *uses-features* in other application and it shows just fine, it seems to be a problem regarding this specific app. *glEsVersion* means that we need *OpenGL ES version 2.0* for it to work.